# Running rake routes on Rails 5 giving instantiation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm trying to setup a barebones Rails app. So far I have generated a sample Article model, added some records to the database, edited my routes config to the following:

```
Rails::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end
```

But when I run `bin/rake routes`, `bundle exec rake routes`, and just `rake routes` I receive the following error:

```
$ bin/rake routes                                                                                                                               (articles-controller✱)
rake aborted!
Rails::Application is abstract, you cannot instantiate it directly.
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:206:in `initialize'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:434:in `initialize'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:124:in `initialize'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:162:in `new'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:162:in `instance'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:95:in `instance'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:184:in `method_missing'
/Users/sam/turing/2module/personal_work/projects/blogger/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `call'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/activesupport-5.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/Users/sam/turing/2module/personal_work/projects/blogger/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/railties-5.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
Tasks: TOP => routes => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas? All of my gems are up to date using `bundle update`

Answer (score 4):

Oops, looks like the syntax for the routes.rb file is a bit different in Rails 5. For anyone else with this issue, the syntax for the do block is `Rails.application.routes.draw do`, not `Rails::Application.routes.draw do`